# How can I display posts from another wordpress site to my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have 2 wordpress blog site. One site has a custom post type. I want to show contents from this custom post type to my another wordpress site?

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

On the site with the CPT, be sure that CPT is exposed to the REST API (you can do this in the CPT code) and then use the REST API to pull them into your other site https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: I tried but not working but not working. May be I can't understand the process. Can you please show me an example?

Comment: You were given the ressources you need to complete this task. If you can't do, you might want to hire a developer.

Comment: This may not render correctly if the two sites do not share common CSS files. @Jamil Hossen suggest you use the command line utility curl to retrieve a post to get an understanding of how REST works. For something this simple I don't think you should use the Backbone.js client library in the documentation. To expose the CPT see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694650/get-custom-posts-using-the-wp-rest-api/51695088#51695088

Comment: In theory it should render fine.. after all, they are only 'blogs'. As for an example, look at what I linked..

Comment: It depends - if the CPT has content that includes CSS selectors that are defined only for its native site. For example, it may uses shortcodes implemented by plugins that are only on the native site. If these plugins load custom CSS files then these custom CSS files will not be loaded on the foreign site.

Comment: The WordPress REST API will return both 'raw' and 'rendered' post content but the rendered post content (rendered means that the 'the_content' filter was applied) is just HTML which may contain CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Ashley Brown is technically correct but with respect to your problem which is very simple the documentation will be somewhat confusing as the documentation describes REST API access in general which is more complicated. Your case fortunately is very simple and will require very little code.

First, the WordPress REST API will return 'rendered' post content. This 'rendered' post content is the result of applying the filter 'the_content' to the post content. In particular, it may contain CSS selectors. It is important that the foreign site also load the CSS files of the native site that is used by the CPT. This may mean if the CPT is from a plugin and that plugin loads CSS files you may need install that plugin on the foreign site.

Second, use your browser to retrieve a URL with the REST API from the native site. E.g, try something like the following:

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1
```

This will return JSON with a field content.rendered which in above URL looks like the following:

```
<p>line first&#8230;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>AAA return &#8216;hello&#8217; . &#8216; &#8216; . &#8216;world&#8217;; ZZZ</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>line last&#8230;</p>\n
```

It is just raw HTML.

So you can use an AJAX request to retrieve a JSON object and extract the content.rendered field from this object. Then use jQuery.append() (or something similiar) to insert that HTML into your DOM.

There is one more thing the CPT must be enabled for REST access. see my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694650/get-custom-posts-using-the-wp-rest-api/51695088#51695088) regarding how to do this.

ADDENDUM

It occurs to me that someone would have written a plugin for this kind of basic functionality. I found this [REST API Post Embeds](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-post-embeds/). I know nothing about this plugin and there maybe other plugins that are better but this functionality is so basic and so easy to implement that there must be a plugin that does this.